# How to convert &[u8] into &[u8; 64]?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I'm writing code that takes 64-byte blocks and I want to enforce this size at the type level:

```rust
fn f(buf: &[u8; 64]) { ... }
```

However, the data is coming in as a slice `&[u8]`. So, I'd like to be able to take subspaces of this and convert to `&[u8; 64]`. It turns out that it the following conversion works:

```rust
let buf = (0..32).collect::<Vec<u8>>();
let z: &[u8; 32] = &(&buf[..]).try_into().unwrap();
```

But the following doesn't:

```rust
let buf = (0..64).collect::<Vec<u8>>();
let z: &[u8; 64] = &(&buf[..]).try_into().unwrap();
```

The difference being from 0 to 32 inclusive, the conversion works, but not for sizes above 32. What can I do to enable this `&[u8]` -> `&[u8; 64]` conversion without manually doing data copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If so desired, you could use [the code that Rust currently uses](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/7979016aff545f7b41cc517031026020b340989d/src/libcore/array.rs#L142-L157) for sizes 0-32.

```
#[stable(feature = "try_from", since = "1.34.0")]
impl<'a, T, const N: usize> TryFrom<&'a [T]> for &'a [T; N]
where
    [T; N]: LengthAtMost32,
{
    type Error = TryFromSliceError;

    fn try_from(slice: &[T]) -> Result<&[T; N], TryFromSliceError> {
        if slice.len() == N {
            let ptr = slice.as_ptr() as *const [T; N];
            unsafe { Ok(&*ptr) }
        } else {
            Err(TryFromSliceError(()))
        }
    }
}
```

When constant generics are stabilized, the bound `[T; N]: LengthAtMost32` will presumably be removed. Until then, you can implement your own function. Either use nightly with constant generics enabled or simply have a function for your specific size.

```
struct TryFromSliceError(());

fn slice_to_array_64<T>(slice: &[T]) -> Result<&[T; 64], TryFromSliceError> {
    if slice.len() == 64 {
        let ptr = slice.as_ptr() as *const [T; 64];
        unsafe {Ok(&*ptr)}
    } else {
        Err(TryFromSliceError(()))
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9e8441e8e417dfeb1368d8c1aea2f46)

Comment: You could also write `struct TryFromSliceError;` and create an instance with `Err(TryFromSliceError)`, so you don't need the unit type as a struct member.

Comment: @hellow Yep. I just copied what the standard library has. I think it's so instances can't be created outside of the module.